# update column value based on inserted value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

**Travel Table**

```
tid  | tname |  countryid  | status 
1    | a     |      1      |
```

**PassengerTravel**

```
tid |   passengerid
1   |      1
1   |      2
```

i want update status column in table 1  if insert in passenger Travel table 
and update status column  if print the travel application for them

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me, but if you want to update the travel table upon insert to passenger travel, then a trigger might work here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do with your code ?

the first one it can use trigger to manage it.

the second you print with your application right ?

why not let the code to update this.